# How to set SSL certificates dynamically based on request domain?

Tags: ssl, apache2, apache2.4

I am trying to setup a dynamic apache virtual host configuration with SSL.

Consider i have 3 domains example1.com, example2.com and example3.com and their project folders resides in /var/www/html/.
eg.
example1.com - /var/www/html/example1/
example2.com - /var/www/html/example2/
example3.com - /var/www/html/example3/

I have configured apache to form self-referential URLs from domain setting UseCanonicalName to Off.  Referred this doc [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html).
My conf looks like this

```
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It worked fine for HTTP requests.

Issue #1
I want to include SSL certificates dynamically but failed. I tried by adding

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/abc/certs/%1/domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/abc/certs/%1/domain.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/abc/certs/%1/domain.ca-bundle
```

It throwed

```
SSLCertificateFile: file '/home/abc/certs/%1/domain.crt' does not exist or is empty
```

How can i fix this? is there way to set ssl from DB?

Issue #2\

After using the above vhost configuration, apache fails to map the dedicated server name.

```
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/devportal
    <Directory "/var/www/html/devportal">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The above VirtualDocumentRoot overrides other virutalhost blocks. When I tried enclosing the VirtualDocumentRoot inside a VirtualHost block, dev.example.com works but other domains points to default apache html.
I am not able to figureout what was my mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SSLCertificateFile /home/abc/certs/%1/domain.crt
```

This can't be done. It needs to have a static path name since the certificates are loaded at startup, not on TLS handshake.

Comment: Is there any way i can load SSL dynamically? Does apache provide any other solution?

Comment: @Abishek: As far as I know you cannot load certificates dynamically. You need to include all domains statically in the config. But if all the names are known you can create certificates which cover multiple names.

Comment: I wont know the domain up front that's the reason i want to make it dynamic. Anyway thanks for your answer.